# AttributeError "SQLAlchemy" object has no attribute 'create'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create the db in sqlalchemy with `db.create.all()` but I'm getting this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'create'
```

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from  datetime import datetime 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db= SQLAlchemy(app)

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False )
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False , default='N/A')
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False ,default= datetime.utcnow())
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'BlogPost' + str(self.id)
```

Comment: Do you mean `db.create_all()` vs `db.create.all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be `db.create_all()` instead of `db.create.all()`.